# Using OUTPUT for SQL Server 2008 on update?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2008 with GUIDs in all my tables and using some stored procedures. I want to know if there is a way to output the current GUID that you are updating to?

I know there is the codes below that I use in other procedures:

```
output inserted.*
output deleted.*
```

However, I have a case that is an if null insert, else, update. I would like to know which GUID was used in each case. I have heard another way where you create another table, set the value in the table to that the just updated GUID and then SELECT the value from the newly created table, but that just seems extremely redundant and unnecessary. Any workarounds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have newid() as the default for the column or are you generating a guid in your code when you do insert/update?

If you have a default on it of NewID() then there isn't a way to grab the last inserted/updated one, had it been identity you could have used @@IDENTITY to get the last inserted ID.

Only way I can think of to do what you want is to take the default off the column, generate a NewID() in your code for insert and remember what that was.

(This answer was made with the assumption you're using GUIDS as PK's)

Comment: Well it works for inserted values.  I still use the default for the GUID row as NEWID() and it works fine. However, the Update one will not pass back the GUID.  Not a huge issue for me, but its inconvenient for sure.

Comment: Is the GUID the PK?  If so then you already know it when you to the update.  Otherwise just add code to select the guid based on the same table/where clause as the update to fetch the one you just updated.